CAPM and Marginal Utility: How does this derivation work?
I came across this obstacle in the book Foreign Exchange: Practical Asset Pricing and Macroeconomic Theory by Adam.S.Iqbal(I have attached screenshots below)
For 1.40 the author claims that we must substitute 1.39 into 1.36. I am pretty sure he meant we must substitute 1.37 into 1.36 to get 1.40
My real trouble is how did he go from 1.41 to 1.42. Substituting the rearranged b from 1.41 into 1.40  does not give us 1.42
In 1.40 the b constant was out of the Cov function. All of a sudden -b is back in the cov function in 1.42 while b is also on the outside. Basically, what the author is saying initially is -Cov(-bX,X) = bCov(X,X). Then all of a sudden in 1.42 he ends up with bCov(-bX,X)
Totally lost.
Thank you very much.



Algebraically, if you equate (1.41) and (1.40) on $b$, I find two mistakes in (1.42): first, the covariance in the numerator should be $Cov(R^M_{t+1}, R_{t+1})$ which coincide with the beta equation on wiki and (1.42) becomes equivalent to the second last equation in this derivation. Secondly, the missing brackets around $E\left[R^M_{t+1}\right] - R_F$. Did you find an errata for the book? Maybe the author is aware of the mistake(s)?

I never managed to find an Errata for the book, unfortunately.

Oh, ok. Unless I have missed some underlying assumptions or similar, I would assume they are simple mistakes in the book (the wrong covariance in numerator and the missing brackets).

@Pleb I was hoping for someone to confirm this. Thank you very much. Highly appreciate it!

@Pleb sorry to comment a month later, but I came back again to these equations but this time I realized something very weird is going on between equations 1.37 to 1.39. For example, on equation 1.38 he doesn't seem to include any subscript to include what time that return is indicated for (I'm guessing that's a typo and there should be t+1 there as well.) and it doesn't make too much sense how he got 1.39 from 1.38. Just want to be double sure. Thank you.
